# QGIS Atlas Catalogue

Tags: qgis-2

I would like to know if I can set the filters to only show the current feature the map is focused on and hide the other features around it?

I currently have a layer of points which the atlas centers on. If there is another point close to this, I would like to hide it so it doesn't show on the atlas created image. Is this possible please?

Answer (score 2):

Rule-based labeling on your point layer will accomplish this nicely.

In your layer's style tab, change the labeling type to `Rule-based` then add the following rule to your styling:

```
$id = @atlas_featureid
```

[image: rule-based style with $id = @atlas_featureid rule]

This will hide all but the current atlas feature. You may find it useful to add an additional style and restrict it to canvas only:
[image: added rule for canvas only]

The second style (edit by double-click) will only display on your main map canvas for editing, the second style will display as well, but only the atlas feature.