# "You Are Here" symbol for maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

This is a very generic map production question in QGIS.
I am trying to add a "You are here" symbol in QGIS layouts for a fire evacuation map like this one below?

[image]

There are more than one "You Are Here" points depending on the location. So I was thinking of adding a point table with all "You Are Here" locations and then in Composer have automatically created these symbols.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you are using the map atlas, you can hide all but the current feature: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228079/qgis-atlas-catalogue

Comment: I think @JGH's suggestion is the way to go. Create "you are here" symbols for all the points *in the map canvas*. Then filter them based on the atlas.